# jQuery UI autocomplete - syntax for external javascript data source?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-autocomplete

and thanks in advance for reading.  I'm attempting to customize the jQuery UI autocomplete search to display results that are clickable links, and I've been successful. I've successfully mimiced code from another question on this forum.

However, I will eventually have too many links to store on the page as a variable. I used to use the old version of jQuery autocomplete (before it became jQuery UI) and was able to store the variable "updates" in a javascript file.  With the new version in UI, I don't know to do it.  The old version was here...

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/

And the javascript file used there was "localdata.js"

Does anyone know how to change the source from a variable on the same HTML page to a external javascript file that has the exact same text as my variable in the jQuery UI version???

I've also tried the migration guide here;  http://www.learningjquery.com/2010/06/autocomplete-migration-guide but I was not able to figure this out.

The working code I have, that doesn't reference an outside file is below...

====================================================

```
    <script>
    $(function() {


    var updates = [ 

    { value: "http://www.google.com", label: "Google"},
    { value: "http://www.yahoo.com", label: "Yahoo!"},
    ];

    $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: updates,
    select: function( event, ui ) { 
    window.location.href = ui.item.value;
    }
    });
    });
    </script>
```

=====================================

I know the change is on the "source;updates," line, but I don't know what to do.  Thank you very, very much again for reading.

Comment: I have the exact same array "var updates = [...." EXACTLY AS IT IS on the original HTML file.  I'm saying the source is "source:array.js" but it seems that jQuery UI wants some formatting or query and responses with PHP???? WHY?!  The demos are so poorly documented.  ALL OF THIS IS IN JAVASCRITPT - how does it not know what to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish it is to store your data in a JSON format in a separate file. Taking your example you could convert your updates array into a valid JSON:

```
[{"value": "http://www.google.com", "label": "Google"},
 {"value": "http://www.yahoo.com", "label": "Yahoo!"}]
```

(please notice double quotes around the keys and values and no need for a variable) and then save it in the updates.json file. With this setup you can then set `source` in autocomplete to updates.json:

```
$("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
  source: "updates.json",
  select: function( event, ui ) { 
    window.location.href = ui.item.value;
  }
});
```

This assumes you will serve your file from the same domain (autocomplete also supports calls from remote domains via JSONP).